# Data type for changing size of shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My VBA code works very well. I can change multple size of shapes, but is working only for rounded numbers. If I wand to change size of shape to be 2.5 or 5.5 is not working, but data type of variable is double. Any ideas?

Thank you

```
Function ConvertPointToCm(ByVal pnt As Double) As Double
ConvertPointToCm = pnt * 0.03527778
End Function

Function ConvertCmToPoint(ByVal cm As Double) As Double
ConvertCmToPoint = cm * 28.34646
End Function


Sub test()

Dim objHeigh As Double
Dim objWidth As Double
Dim oSh As Shape

On Error GoTo CheckErrors

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
If .Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You need to select a shape first"
    Exit Sub
End If
End With

 objHeigh = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh"))
' give the user a way out
If objHeigh = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
objHeigh = ConvertCmToPoint(objHeigh)

objWidth = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Width", "Width"))
' give the user a way out
If objWidth = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
objWidth = ConvertCmToPoint(objWidth)

For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
If objName <> "" Then
    oSh.Name = objName
End If

oSh.Height = CInt(objHeigh)
  oSh.Width = CInt(objWidth)
Next
Exit Sub

CheckErrors: MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use `CInt` in

```
objHeigh = CInt(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh"))
```

casting the result as an `integer`.
So, **the answer should be as below:**

```
objHeigh = CDbl(InputBox$("Assign a new size of Height", "Heigh"))
```

Comment: Why don't you update your answer to advise to use `CDbl` instead - it will make it a better answer ;-)

Comment: Re: `Robin` yup, just revised. Thanks

Comment: Re: `Norby` if you find the answer helpful, may you please mark it as acceptable answer, thanks so much : )

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working! Answer has been marked

Comment: happy to be helpful : )

Comment: @Grace FYI, use "@" and the username of the user you are trying to notify to notify them of your comment